# Terrain classification for self-driving vehicle

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

So I just started in researching in terrain classification for self-driving vehicles. Basically I wish to distinguish grass, road, building, people and mud etc from the camera. I've experience with single object recognizing and tracking through convolutional neural networks. But multiple object tracking seems much more difficult.

One option I have is to train a single object localizer for each object and merge them together. But I have to do a lot of manual localizing by myself in order to train my model and it doesn't seems to be a very wise way. I looked through some paper in literature but didn't find what I want.

I wonder do anyone have experience with it or any ideas and resources?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJMtDRbqH40)? If yes, it's called semantic segmentation. You will wind a ton of information on [Awesome Deep Vision](https://github.com/kjw0612/awesome-deep-vision#semantic-segmentation) repo.